# How can I use process_request in Django for checking if the request contains the header I require?

Tags: python, django

I am have a Django app with a decent amount of views. What I wish to do is that whenever a request is sent to the app, it gets checked for headers, and if the header `SECRET` has the value `$ecret$tring`, only then the request is matched with my urlpatterns and sent to the view. Else, it should return the following-

```
{'MESSAGE': 'UNAUTHORIZED'}
```

with a 401 status. Here is the middleware class that I have written-

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class AuthCheck(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'SECRET' in request.headers:
            if request.headers['SECRET'] != '$ecret$tring':
                return JsonResponse({'MESSAGE': 'UNAUTHORIZED'}, status=401)
        
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'MESSAGE': 'UNAUTHORIZED'}, status=401)
```

However, when I send a request without the header, it still gets sent to the view. What's going  wrong?

Comment: What if you work with `'Secret' in `request.headers`? Can you `print(request.headers)`? since Django does some preprocessing with these headers.

Comment: Oddly enough, after I added ```print(request.headers)``` in the ```process_request``` function and sent a request, nothing was printed in my terminal. Does that mean it is not being called at all?

Comment: did you *register* the middelware in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting?

Comment: Out of all the things I could do wrong, I made the silliest error! Spent half an hour trying to figure this out even though I have written so many custom middlewares before. Thank you and sorry for the trouble, I had indeed forgotten to register it.